# Когда лучше писать запрос непосредственно в коде, а когда лучше описать их в виде процедур на сервере?

Tags: c#, sql, база-данных, .net, sql-server

Как наиболее грамотно работать с SQL из C#?

Существуют ли какие-нибудь соглашения хорошего тона? Сейчас я могу, писать запросы непосредственно в коде C# и обернуть это в методу,

могу так же все запросы обернуть в процедуры (вплоть до `Select * from table`) и дергать их через код.

Где золотая середина?

Я почитал несколько паттернов, но не один не ответил на вопрос, когда лучше использовать процедуры, а когда лучше описать для этого отдельный метод. И так и так код будет работать, но другой вопрос:"Как грамотно?"

Если обернуть все процедурами, то код будет, на мой взгляд чище, так как не будет не привычных для языка строк "SELECT * from t JOIN t2...", а будет просто что-то типа "exec Report". Но нигде я не нашел подтверждения своей точки зрения.

Answer (score 0):

Для одноразовых запросов (конвертация БД к примеру) проще писать прямо в коде.

Для регулярных запросов (получение данных, обновление выборки, ещё какая то частая операция) - либо какая то ORM, либо процедуры в базе.

При Core-First подходе (когда приложение при первом запуске например способно само создать базу) процедуры в базе ещё надо создать, что меня например несколько не устраивает и я обычно прикручиваю nHibernate и оставляю сложные запросы на его совести.

Отдельно стоит подумать вот о чём:

1. Приложения иногда пишут с поддержкой разных баз - тогда возможно всё проще держать в коде.
2. Иногда для базы пишут приложения на разных языках - тогда лучше единую процедуру в базе, а в приложении её только вызывать.
3. Если и баз может быть много и приложений к ним много, то это пора сваливать на отдельный сервис - т.е. сервис с ORM умеет взаимодействовать с несколькими типами баз и дает возможность разным клиентам к ним подключаться. Запросы в этом случае разрешены только для сервиса (защита от некорректных клиентских запросов важна), а клиенту вообще без разницы, пользуется сервис базой или как то иначе хранит информацию.

Comment: А в чём отличие NHibernate?

Comment: @VladD добавил пояснение.

Comment: Хм, а EF не справляется? Вы доверяете совести NH больше? (Это не сарказм, я и правда не в курсе.)

Comment: @VladD, я сейчас уже не помню, на что я ориентировался при первом выборе, но EF в чем то показался неудобен. Если не сложно - может EF настраивать маппинг кодом, не трогая классы сущностей, не заставляя помечать их аттрибутами?

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, да: [EF Fluent API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx).

Comment: @VladD, тогда принципиальной разницы не вижу, привычка - дело такое. С EF по крупному не работал, в отличие от хибера.

Comment: Понял, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Хранить запросы в приложении не самый лучший вариант с точки зрения безопасности/надежности (если предполагается использование нескольких клиентов с различными правами доступа) и управления изменениями. С точки зрения производительности [одно и тоже](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/073562609X). Сейчас все действительно переходят на ORM, удобнее, надежнее и "расширяемее".

Comment: Запросы у меня хранятся не на клиенте, а в службе. Клиент общается со службой.

Comment: Я стараюсь избегать ORM. На мой взгляд некоторые операции выглядят менее естественно и более красивее выглядит, если делать прямые запросы

Comment: @iluxa1810 это пока у вас схема не меняется и кода мало. ORM позволяет не задумываясь о хранении \ названии свойств в базе спокойно работать с обычными классами. Не надо писать ни строчки sql чтобы создать класс, сохранить его в базе, изменить его свойства.

Comment: Все равно ORM не освобождает от того, что если в базе , допустим, пропадет колонка, то придется править код. Так что и там и там, что-то придется менять. Ручное написание запросов, делает запросы более производительными.

Comment: @iluxa1810 Это Вы описываете довольно редкую ситуацию, относительно всего многообразия SQL-запросов, нужда в которых возникает постоянно на текущем источнике данных, который не меняется довольно долго или вообще не менялся никогда.

Comment: @iluxa1810 а непосредственно по вопросу, учитывая что у Вас промежуточная служба на самом деле контактирует с БД, то вообще без разницы. Единственный критерий, куда Вам лучше\проще залезать для суппорта и обновлений - в службу или СУБД. А да, еще у хранимых процедур есть небольшое преимущество - часть СУБД и БД. Соответственно бэкапить, документировать взаимодействия с БД гораздо удобнее.

Comment: >если в базе , допустим, пропадет колонка, то придется править код -- некоторые умеют валидировать такие поля на старте, а в случае ручной работы - вы можете рухнуть посреди рабочей сессии.

Comment: Ну допустим в коде используется sum(price). Если эту колонку грохнут, то как поможет валидация? Код автоматически перепишется и уберет строчки кода и методы? По любому придется лезть в код и удалять лишние методы или менять логику. Что так , что так придется править код.

Comment: Если грохают колонку вдруг осознав ее ненадобность или опасность, когда накручено уже софта - то это уже вопрос как проектировали БД. Здесь действительно ничто не поможет и придется лезть в код. Но в серьезных решениях принято и приятно разделять по уровням. Вот ORM позволяет отделить бизнес от данных. Ключевая вещь при построении больших систем

Comment: Ну не знаю... Все равно мне ОРМ не нравится... Он может генерить неоптимальные планы запросов, что критично в больших БД, да и сам LINQ выглядит менее выразительным, если речь доходит до соединений... На мой взгляд соединения красивее через прямые запросы.

Comment: @iluxa1810 у вас уже есть проблемы конкретные с запросами и неоптимальными планами? ORM - решение универсальное, а для своей базы всегда можно добавить вручную написанных запросов под частые и\или тяжелые случаи.